# CodeIgniter Custom Errors for Forms?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` to display my CI errors and I am wondering if it is possible to include custom errors (like if the username/password is incorrect?).

I tried `$this->form_validation->set_message("Password or Username was incorrect");`

However it didn't work. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with CALLBACK.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: In the callback function, you can load your MODEL and check if username or password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to display an error for what is wrong, if you want to test if the user exist make a callback to check if the user exist and set the message for that validation,
if you want to check if the password is ok, make another callback with another message